# How to expand <a> and <li> to fit the width of the <ul> using css? (or even jquery)

Tags: jquery, html, css, width

I have been struggling over this for a while, so would appreciate some help.

**EDIT**

I have tried the answer below but it seems some of my other css is causing it to not work. Can anyone tell me what I need to change? Thanks!
http://jsfiddle.net/tnuF8/3/

---

I have a drop-down menu, and I have managed to get each drop down to be the `width` of the longest link in that menu. My problem is that the shorter links are not the entire width of the menu, so do not respond to click or roll-over when the mouse is not over the text of the link.

Is there a way that I can expand the `<a>` and `<li>` (I am not sure if the `<li>` is already expanding) so that all links are the complete width?

I think the problems that I am having are to do `width 100%` in css not taking into account borders, padding, etc. The padding on the `<ul>` is important as the site background is the same colour as the hover, so I want padding / a border on the menu to separate them.

html:

```
<div id="nav" style="position: relative; float: right;">
    <ul id="ddmenu">
        <li>
            <a href="#">Company</a>
            <ul class="sub-menu">
                <li><a class="sub-link" href="#">Something</a></li>
                <li><a class="sub-link" href="#">Short</a></li>
                <li><a class="sub-link" href="#">Something Long</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

css:

```
#nav ul.sub-menu {
    padding: 12px 5px 5px 5px;
}

#nav ul.sub-menu li a
{
    display: inline-block;
}

#nav ul.sub-menu li
{
    display: inline-block;
    white-space: nowrap;
    width: inherit;
}

#nav ul li a:hover
{
    color: #000;
    background-color: rgb(244, 244, 244);
}
```

Many thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
#nav ul.sub-menu li a
{
    display: block;
}
#nav ul.sub-menu li
{
    display: block; // actually the default value
    white-space: nowrap;
    width: inherit;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/tnuF8/

**UPDATE**

In addition, remove the following styles:

```
#nav ul.sub-menu li
{
    display: block;
    white-space: nowrap;
/*  width: inherit;*/
}
#ddmenu li a {
    display: block;
/*  float: left;*/
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/h3NAt/

Comment: Hmm, that is not working in my page at the moment, so I must have some conflicting css. I will try to work out what...

Comment: Thank you so much, that has taken up so much time today!

Comment: Most browsers have a "DOM debugger" (look for "Developer Tools" in the menus) which, among other things, lets you select an element on the page and turn on or off individual CSS styles, to see what happens to the page in real-time. Try to find it in your favorite browser; it can be tricky to learn, but it might help you solve these issues in the future.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, but I already use the debugger in Chrome. Unfortunately there was a lot of different things that could have been affecting this one and I didn't find the right combination this time :)